# Show equivalent form of $\backsim\left(\forall x {\in} S,P(x) \vee Q(x)\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Question:

${Let‌ ‌S = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n\}}$

Show that

${\backsim\Bigl(\forall ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S,P(x) ‌ ‌\vee ‌ ‌Q(x)\Bigr) \Leftrightarrow
 \exists ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S, ‌\Bigl( ‌\backsim P(x) ‌ ‌\wedge ‌ ‌\backsim Q(x)\Bigr)}$

---

This is what I have done so far ...

${\backsim\Bigl(\forall ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S,P(x) ‌ ‌\vee ‌ ‌Q(x)\Bigr) \Leftrightarrow
 \exists ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S, ‌\Bigl( ‌\backsim P(x) ‌ ‌\wedge ‌ ‌\backsim Q(x)\Bigr)}$

${\exists ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S,  ‌\backsim P(x) ‌ ‌\wedge ‌ ‌\backsim Q(x)\Leftrightarrow
 \exists ‌x ‌{\in} ‌S, ‌\Bigl( ‌\backsim P(x) ‌ ‌\wedge ‌ ‌\backsim Q(x)\Bigr)}$

And then I have no I idea how to continue from here.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: That is Quantifier negation ($\neg\forall{x}{Px}\iff \exists{x}{\neg Px}$), with DeMorgan's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Without nailing down which axioms of logic can be used one has to be satisfied with an intuitive verification.

Pls, consider the following figures.

[image]

In $S$, the red elements are those that have property $P$, the blue elements are those that have property $Q$, and the purple elements have both properties. The upper figure depicts the situation when 
$$\forall x {\in} S,\color{red}{P(x)}  \vee  \color{blue}{Q(x)}.$$

The lower figure depicts the negation: There are elements that neither of the two properties have (white). This can be described by

$$\sim \left[\forall x {\in} S,\color{red}{P(x)}  \vee  \color{blue}{Q(x)}\right].$$

The lower figure clearly shows that there are then elements that neither the two properties have (white). In other word these existing white elements that don't have property $Q$  **and** they don't have property $P$. This can be described as

$$\exists x {\in} S, \left[ \backsim \color{red}{P(x)}  \wedge  \backsim \color{blue}{Q(x)}\right].$$

The argumentation can be replayed in the other direction.